# Why serverless functions (e.g. AWS Lambda) have zip file size limit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I am wondering why do serverless functions have such a small size limit when deploying?

E.g. AWS lambda zipped function with dependencies can not exceed 50MB. Why such a low limit?

Thank you!

Comment: Low and high are subjective terms. It depends what is low and high for the person :-) In general limits are great, they help to see when our solution becomes bad. Function has single responsibility. How many MBs do you want to dedicate to source code of a function that has a single responsibility? Having no limits people will upload 1 TB of shit there, in this case other uses will experience issues while using Lambda.

Comment: Well, single responsibility could be hosting a 1TB M.L. model ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you need to push zip more than 50 MB on lambda you can tweak your design and use it ?

So 50 MB lambda+250 MB Layer  = 300 MB

AES Layers  -
" Layers make it possible to run Lambda functions with custom runtime code. One of the most exciting benefits that layers brought to Lambda, was the ability to run Lambda functions in any programming language. "

> When building serverless applications, it is quite common to have code
>   that is shared across Lambda functions. It can be your custom code,
>   that is used by more than one function, or a standard library, that
>   you add to simplify the implementation of your business logic.

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-use-any-programming-language-and-share-common-components/
- Create Lambda function deployment package upto max 50 MB size (.zip/.jar file)
- Create another big size of code/dependencies that you can zip into a deployment package (.zip/.jar size)

Note : Store file in S3 bucket and upload then package size can be greater than 50 MB ,if uploaded through S3 instead of uploading directly.

**UPDATE :-**  Why ? , limitation

AWS Lambda limits to have an effective internal capacity planning of their resources in place , whenever release any product to external development team did testing and bench mark analysis and share best practice and limitations.

Following possible reason for limitation :

1) When invoke labda function then it will start environment provisioning and loading your code and execute , if your updload file size big then this cold start will be take long time.

2) Concurrency :

> AWS Lambda allows you to use normal language and operating system
>   features, such as creating additional threads and processes. Resources
>   allocated to the Lambda function, including memory, execution time,
>   disk, and network use, must be shared among all the threads/processes
>   it uses

However CPU available to Lambda function is shared among all threads  and  thread will not get more CPU in a Lambda function by running work in parallel so thread start starving and sleep very long , if you are hitting lambda with concurrent request then lambda will start new container to support your request and again big file size start adding latancy here.

Comment: I am not saying I need more space. It was a question to understand the underlying structure and limitation and philosophy behind this.

But thank you for an extensive answer, appreciate it!

Comment: In my articale i have explained in detail , let me update answwer als 
      https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/aws-lambda-mysql-rds-api-gateway-vaquar-khan-/

Comment: It is not 50 for the .zip + 250 for the layers. The max size of a lambda deployment, unzipped, including layers is 250 MB, or 50 MB zipped. Layers just adds the ability to pull out dependencies so that it can easily be used by multiple lambdas. It does not increase the max size of a lambda.

Answer (score 3):

The idea of the serverless concept and of Lambda is to have "small" functions (i.e. with not too much code) that have a single responsibility. If the size of your packaged code is greater than 50 MB, either there is an issue with your packaging, or you have way too much code in your function and you should re-think your design (maybe the task you want to execute inside the function is so huge that Lambda is not the right tool for it?).

Plus, as others wrote, the code size of a Lambda function is limited because Lambda needs to load and initialize the whole thing on every cold start (invocation) of the function.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand.

Once you push the first request to lambda (or cold start), AWS will download and unzip, then prepare env to run the function.

If function was large, Its may take a long time to pull and unzip, execute.

Comment: Yup. Keeps the cold-start time down.